# Why is this React component separated into two?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I get the difference between connected and unconnected components, but what is the utility in separating ALL components in this manner?  All connected components rely on unconnected and vice-versa, so I'm not seeing why this pattern exists.

**Connected component**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import PrivacyPolicyUI from './PrivacyPolicyUI';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {    
    return { };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { };
};

const PrivacyPolicy = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(PrivacyPolicyUI);

export default PrivacyPolicy;
```

**Unconnected component**

```
import React from 'react';

const PrivacyPolicyUI = () => (
    <div> ** some content ** </div>

);
export default PrivacyPolicyUI;
```

Comment: give this a read: http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/the-react-plus-redux-container-pattern/

Comment: You mean why you have separated `PrivacyPolicyUI` into separate file?

Comment: Yes @Aurimas, that is essentially the question.

Comment: And thanks for the read @floor, but it doesn't answer my question.  The article basically says to separate things as much as possible, but doesn't address the specific benefits of this pattern.

Comment: @jmargolisvt It is basically to separate out the ui logic. By keeping them unconnected, you can reuse those little pieces easily in some other connected component.

Comment: @jmargolisvt separation of concerns is the benefit. Having a central place to handle related logic that pushes the data to dumb components makes it easier to reason about your application. Mind you there is arguments against this.

Comment: Thanks @floor.  That's a satisfactory answer although I have yet to see heavy enough reuse of components to justify this pattern.  I'll file this under "good idea, not terribly useful."

Comment: @jmargolisvt it might interest you in taking a look at this: https://github.com/concretesolutions/redux-zero  I had thought it was a neat idea as I am not completely sold on all the boiler plate code that comes with using redux / react-redux

Comment: It sounds a bit like a premature optimization.  It's not terribly difficult to split a file apart later if you wanted to - but it seems pretty expensive to do this, by default.

Comment: I rarely do this, instead I export the connected component by default, and unconnected component as a named export. That said, always doing it the same way is valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally disagree with putting "plain" components and their connections in separate files.  Most of the time there's a 1:1 correspondence between a component and its connection (ie, the `mapState` and call to `connect` are only used with one component, and that component is only used with that call to `connect`).

I have a saved chat log [where I describe why I think separate "containers" / "components" folders are not a good idea](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ea312b5ee398627ffceb09f89904831f).  I also just [wrote some additional comments on Reddit about structuring component connections](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/7gbupl/react_componentscontainers_is_my_thinking_outdated/dqigo8p/?context=3).